# AngulaJS: Why don't checkboxes work in directives? (And how to get them to work?)

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, radio-button, directive

I have simple directive which defines a "field" tag which is translates to an input.

If this input is of type `text` everything is ok. But if it's of type `checkbox` (or `radio`) it stops working.

```
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <h1>This is ok:</h1>
    T1: <input type="text" ng-model="data.aText" ></input><br/>
    T2: <field type="text" model="data.aText" ></field><br/>
    T3: {{data.aText}}
    <hr/>

    <h1>This does not work:</h1>
    C1: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.aBoolean" ></input><br/>
    C2: <field type="checkbox" model="data.aBoolean" ></field><br/>
    C3: {{data.aBoolean}}
    <hr/>

</body>

<script>

var App = angular.module('MyApp', [] );
App.directive( 'field', function(){

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { model: '=', type: '@' },
        replace: false,
        template: '<input ng-model="model" type="{{type}}" />'
    } 
} );
var MyCtrl = function( $scope ){
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.aText = 'Test Text';
    $scope.data.aBoolean = true;
    return $scope;
}


</scipt>
```

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Scheintod/fK2R2/5/

And as a "**Bonus-Question**": Why does even the rendering break if setting `replace: true`?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can only answer the bonus question, it breaks because you set it as an Element (`restrict: "E"`), if you want to replace it, you have to use at least the attribute (`restrict: "A"`) and do something like `<span field ...>`. Why ? Actually it's because Angular need a reference in the DOM to replace, the element you add isn't in the dom, so angular won't find it, it will be impossible to replace it. If you use an attribute restriction, it will be like an anchor in the page for angular telling something like 'Replace This span here !' =)

Comment: @DotDotDot: Thank you for bothering. I really don't understand the explanation. So I tried it: http://jsfiddle.net/Scheintod/AdpWL/1/ and it doesn't change in behaviour.

Comment: I solved this for my case by writing one directive for each input type so that I can hardcode `type="radio"` in the template. But I still don't understand what's making `type` different from other attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your answers :

**1. There was a small issue in your code :**
You used

`<field type="checkbox" ng-model="data.aBoolean"></field>`

which should be :

`<field type="checkbox" model="data.aBoolean"></field>`

That's the reason why your code was not working even if you set `replace : true`

**2. you were overwriting type attribute  :**
You were using custom attribute `type` and setting it by html attribute `type`. which was causing `type="checkbox type"`.

So you can simply avoid declaring custom attribute `type`.

Here is corrected fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rC36m/1/

Comment: @1: Ok. Thanks. To much copy & paste.

Comment: @2: This seems to only work because of some "magic" copying the type in the first element in the template. If I put a `<div>` around the input it stops working: http://jsfiddle.net/rC36m/2/ (I tried to use the simplest possible example but it seems it was too simple.) So is there a way to get this working with the divs around the input?

Comment: @2: Oh. And what makes `type` a custom attribute?